# Convergenece in distribution of a sum of random variable products

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

> Suppose that $(X_n)$ is sequence of independent variables with $\mathcal E (\lambda)$ distribution, and $(Y_n)$ is sequence of independent variables with $\mathcal G (p)$ distribution, and for each $n \in\mathbb N$ variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent. If $$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i Y_i$$ examine convergence in distribution of sequence of random variables $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}S_n$

Since $X_n Y_n$ has the same distribution for each $n$, by Kolmogorov's theorem
, I can deduce that $$\frac{S_n-\mathbf E S_n}{n} \longrightarrow_{\mathrm{a.s.}} 0,$$ which gives me that $S_n/n  \rightarrow_{\mathrm{a.s.}} 1/\lambda p $. But I think this is a dead end?

Other idea was to find moment generating function for $S_n$, but I got nasty sums.

Does someone have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: You have a sum of i.i.d. random variables and you are supposed to examine the limiting bahaviour of the sum normalized by $\sqrt n$. This just screams 'Central Limit Theorem'. I am not saying that it necessarily applies here, just that it would be the first thing to consider in this setting.